# where to keep page specific script

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to website development, it is recommended to keep all the script in a file.
But how about if I have a specific page script, should I put that also in my script file?

If yes, then suppose I have a `button` with some `id` in a particular page with a `onclick` event. If I put it in the common file, will it not be a overhead, Will the browser try to unnecessarily try to find the `button` with the `id` ?

But on the other hand, if I keep the script in a page, the maintainability of code goes for a toss.

Please guide me, how can I keep my code clean and maintainable?

Comment: Whenever I am using page specific scripts and they are only a few lines I place it on the page. If its longer I will use an external file.

Answer (score 1):

If a script appears on more than one page, it belongs in an external file. If it only needs to be on one page, AND is only a few lines long (so easy to maintain), then it should be in that file.

You should be using an if statement to detect if the button exists before trying to do anything with it. In that case, it will not add overhead to the page, and you can use a common script file. Also remember that browsers can cache javascript files, so including your common code in a single file that is used on every page reduces overall average page load times.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion (and this **is** and opinion), scripts should *always* be in external files.

If you need to use a script on one page only, it's OK to include it on that page alone.

The problem with adding script inline on the page is that subsequent requests to that page will have to reload the script every time. If the script was external, it'd be cached by the browser. If you ever decide you want to use the script on a second page, it'll be easier to dump in if it's already an external file.

Remember, everything starts as a one-off.

To address the question about including the short script on every page, run performance analytics on how much the execution of that one-off affects the page performance. I often write scripts with the following structure (jQuery used for brevity):

```
$('.widget').each(function () {
    $(this).widget($(this).data('widget'));
});
```

Note that if the selection does not match any elements on the page, it will not run the inner function. The overhead for this sort of loading and execution is so minimal that I include these sorts of initializers across entire websites, even if they're only used on one or two pages, because they won't significantly impact the page performance.